# Laravel foreach in a table. Some <tds> are being skipped

Tags: laravel, html-table, eloquent

I have a table for some for each loop. For some records, the title is being skipped, even though it exists. Instead of showing null, there is one less `td` in the row, which skews the table.

Here is the loop

```
 @foreach($comments as $comment)
    <tr>
      <td> {{ $comment->id }}</td>
        @foreach($comment->articles as $article)
          <td>{{ $article->title ?: 'No Title' }}</td>
        @endforeach
      <td>{{ $comment->body ?: 'No Comment' }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Any idea why the title is being skipped in some instances.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the data? Try adding `dd($comments)` in your controller and make sure all comments have articles linked to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put the `td` inside a loop, else you'll end up with messy table, you may need to use a list instead to list the articles:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $comment->id }}</td>
        <td> Articles :
            <ul>
                @foreach($comment->articles as $article)
                    <li>{{ $article->title ?: 'No Title' }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $comment->body ?: 'No Comment' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

That will keep your table with the same size, and organize your article.

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns has to match in the table and the code above is not ensuring that. A comment can has 0 to N articles so you will end with a table containing from 2+0 to 2+N columns. Maybe you can try to show the article titles in a table within the 2nd column and replace the foreach with a forelse and use the loop variable. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade

Something like this

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
<tr>
  <td> {{ $comment->id }}</td>

  <td>
    @forelse($comment->articles as $article)
      @if ($loop->first)
        <table>
      @endif
      @if ($loop->last)
        </table>
      @endif
      <tr><td>{{ $article->title ?: 'No Title' }}</td></tr>
    @else
      No articles
    @endforelse
  </td>

  <td>{{ $comment->body ?: 'No Comment' }}</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code you did mistake in ternary condition

Ternary syntax : `if(condition ? true  : false)`

```
e.g if($article->title=='new' ? $article->title : 'No Title')

@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $comment->id }}</td>
            @foreach($comment->articles as $article)
                <td>{{$article->title ? $article->title  : 'No Title'}}</td>
            @endforeach
        <td>{{ $comment->body ? $comment->body : 'No Comment' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Note : Comment may or maynot have articles so do check for it
e.g

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $comment->id }}</td>
            @foreach($comment->articles as $article)
                @if($article)
                    <td>{{$article->title ? $article->title  : 'No Title'}}</td>
                @else
                    <td>No Article</td>
                @endif  
            @endforeach
        <td>{{ $comment->body ? $comment->body : 'No Comment' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on how you want to display the data, look at this

if comment have 2 article, `<td></td> <td></td>`

what about next comment have 3 article, `<td></td> <td></td> <td></td>`

so your code is breaking the table

```
    @foreach($comment->articles as $article)
      <td>{{ $article->title ?: 'No Title' }}</td>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print title if it's true in a ternary operator. if(condition ? true  : false).

so condition be like

```
    @foreach($comment->articles as $article)
      <td>{{ $article->title != null ? $article->title : 'No Title' }}</td>
    @endforeach
```

if the title will not null it will display title otherwise it will display 'No Title'.

You can change condition as per your requirement. like $article->title != null or $article->title != '' .